# Do data-processing instructions have latency? - Interpreting ARM Cortex A9 Timing Manual

Tags: assembly, arm, timing

I need help with interpreting the ARM Cortex A9 Manual, regarding timing.

[ARM A9 Cycle timings](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.100511_0401_10_en/ric1447333720404.html)

Under the point "Data-processing instructions cycle timings" unit cycle times are given - when I look up the [Multiplication instructions](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.100511_0401_10_en/ric1447333721608.html), cycles AND latency is given - does this impose that e.g. an ADD instruction does not have extra latency?

Comment: Not an expert of ARM. Probably the data processing unit is not pipelined so the latency and the throughput are the same and shown as a single number (e.g.you can `mov` to a register each 2 cycles and each `mov` takes 2 cycles). The multiplication unit is pipelined apparently, the first number ("Cycles") is the throughput (e.g. you can start a `mul` every 2 cycles) and the second the latency (e.g. you get the result after 4 cycles from the beginning of the execution - right when you could start a third `mul`, say).

Comment: Thank you very much for your input, Margaret!

Answer (score 1):

This is related to the pipeline depth of each execution unit.
The image shows a pipeline for an out of order processor (Cortex A-15, the Cortex A9 is also an out of order processor but with a shorter pipeline).
The Integer execution unit is just one cycle, so they do not have extra latency in their execution. However the Multiply execution unit has 4 cycles. This does not means that always is going to take 4 cycles, but depending on the values and number of registers used it may take 4, fewer or more cycles.

[image: pipeline]

Here in the table you can see more detail in the Latency and also the throughput, for example SDIV 1 every 20 to 1 every 4 cycles

[image: Divide and Multiply Instructions]

The table was taken from [Cortex-A57 Software Optimization Guide](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.uan0015b/Cortex_A57_Software_Optimization_Guide_external.pdf)
The pipeline image was taken from here: [Berkeley Design Technology, Inc](https://www.bdti.com/InsideDSP/2011/11/17/ARM)